# Least-squares growth rate in R

Tags: r, regression, average

I need to calculate the average growth rate using the least-squares growth rate approach. A description of this approach is available [here](http://econ.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/DATASTATISTICS/0,,contentMDK:20452034~menuPK:64133152~pagePK:64133150~piPK:64133175~theSitePK:239419,00.html). I don't figure out how to do it with R.

Does anyone have an idea ?

My data are composed by a variable time-varying (y) and another one for years (time).

```
df <- data.frame(
y = sample(28),
time = sample(1990:2017)
)
```

Comment: I have not used this measure before but based on a quick read... It looks like it is just `lm(time~log(y), df)`.  But it is totally possible I am missing something.  Someone more knowledgeable than me may be able to let you know.

Comment: @IanWesley Actually I believe it's the other way around, `fit <- lm(log(y) ~ time, df)` and then compute the growth rate `r` as `r <- exp(coef(fit)[2]) - 1`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas See I knew there was someone smarter, who would know :) That has to count for something right?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I was writing this as an answer but you were faster here